# Send Color value from Processing into Arduino

Tags: serial, rgb-led, processing-lang

I know this has been asked before, but I'm new to Arduino and Processing, and I'm trying to take this step by step.

I would like to pass an RGB value from processing, into Arduino via the Serial.Write/Read.

I have my Processing as:

```
void draw(){

  //orange colour in RGB values
  color _rgbColor = color(255, 40, 0);

  //convert colour into hex
  String _hexColor = hex(_rgbColor, 6);

  //convert colour into binary
  String _binaryColor = binary(_rgbColor);

  //pass colour to port
  myPort.write(_hexColor);
  delay(500);
}
```

I assume I can just pass the HEX value straight across, right?

First problem I get is that I can't debug what my Arduino device is getting (when I run the Processing program, the Serial Monitor wont work. Seems like I can only use one or the other). I can print the myPort.read within my Processing after the delay, and I get:

> -1

So I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong there.

On the Arduino side, I'm using Serial.read() to retrieve the Serial data, which I assume will all be broken down into bytes, so I need to then convert it into a HEX formate, right?

----- Update -----

I now know that I need to break down my color variable into a char-message. I'm guessing I can do something like this then, for example: And then on the other side (Arduino), I need to rebuild the message, right?

```
if(mousePressed == true){
    //Red
     myPort.write('2'); 
     myPort.write('5'); 
     myPort.write('5');
     myPort.write(','); 

     //Green
     myPort.write('0'); 
     myPort.write('3'); 
     myPort.write('0');
     myPort.write(','); 

     //Blue
     myPort.write('0'); 
     myPort.write('0'); 
     myPort.write('0');
     myPort.write('\n'); 
  }
```

My Arduino script is as follows, is this an okay route to go down?

```
String message;
void loop() {

  int _size = Serial.available();

  if(_size > 0){

    char value = Serial.read();
    message += value;

    //full message received (255,255,255)
    if(message.length() == 11){
      String _red = message.substring(0,3);
      String _green = message.substring(4,7);
      String _blue = message.substring(8,11);
      Serial.println("R:" + _red + " G:" + _green + " B:" + _blue);

      //apply to light system
      setColour(_red.toInt(), _green.toInt(), _blue.toInt());

      //clear buffer
      message = "";
      Serial.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should digest this first: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: Also you should understand exactly how the UART protocol (RS-232) works.

Comment: Surely someone, somewhere has already made a defined script for this? To simply pass a colour variable to the Serial?

Comment: Many people have, yes. It is a simple enough operation once you understand how a UART works that it becomes a non-entity and you don't need to really worry about finding special code for it.

Comment: The simplest way is to print the three colour values as a comma-separated line, maybe with a prefix character to indicate the start (`C23,49,119\n` for example). Then it is a case of reading that string and interpreting it properly.

Comment: Okay yes, I now understand that the serial reads one character at a time, thus I need to break down the 'color' to something like '225,40,0\n'. And then rebuild it once received all.

Comment: Yep, you got it. I think processing's Serial.write() just sends one character, so the lowest 8 bits of your HEX colour. You need to print it in such a way that the whole of the data is there, and that takes multiple characters. ASCII is a simple way of doing it, though not very efficient. Quick and dirty is all you need for this though really.

Comment: It also means you can test it easily with the Arduino serial monitor directly without needing your processing program - great for getting the Arduino code right first.

Comment: I've updated my question, does that now make sense? Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: You can probably compress it down using `myPort.print("255,030,000\n");` or even `myPort.print(red); myPort.print(green); myPort.println(blue);` where red, green and blue, are integer variables.

Comment: You need some sort of delimiter or you won't know where one number ends and the next one starts.

Comment: @NickGammon Hello, what do you mean? Surely when the current number ends, and the next on starts is when the next Serial.read comes in?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I was commenting on @Majenko's comment. Doing a "print" on its own is likely to suppress leading zeroes, so you won't be able to tell the difference of 142 being 1 followed by 42, or 14 followed by 2.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add `myPort.print(",");` in between them. My bad.

Comment: As for Serial reads, Serial is a streaming protocol. You don't "read a number" you read a byte. You have no way of knowing when a "number" ends except for the passage of time, fixed length numbers, or finding some delimiter (usually the delimiter would be a "not number").

Comment: I knew Majenko would realize that, I added the comment for the benefit of others reading these comments. :)

Comment: Being Java, in processing you could also: `myPort.println(String.format("%d,%d,%d", red, green, blue));`

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for that reply - but could you elaborate, what does that exactly do differently? '%d'

Comment: %d indicates the presence of an integer in the output string. It formats the string with three numbers from variables with commas between them then outputs it. No messing around with multiple prints.

Answer (score 1):

Add `print(_hexColor);` to you processing sketch. The value it's sending should appear in the Processing Console (at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but actually got a working solution, when I was working out a solution for this.

Code in Processing assuming variable `myPort` is handled in `setup()`:

```java
void draw() {
    int r = 255;
    int g = 123;
    int b = 2;
    myPort.write('S'); // tell the arduino to do something with leds
    myPort.write(r);
    myPort.write(g);
    myPort.write(b);
}
```

Code for Arduino loop:

```cpp
void loop() {
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
  if(Serial.available()) {   
    if(Serial.read() == 'S') {
      while(!Serial.available()){}
      r = Serial.read();
      while(!Serial.available()){}
      g = Serial.read();
      while(!Serial.available()){}
      b = Serial.read();
    }
    delay(10); // some recovery time, not sure if nessecary

    // do something with rgb values
  }
}
```

This works for me with every possible RGB range. It's not the most elegant solution, but by far better then converting between strings/chars and ints with different bit counts on different devices.

Comment: 002 is an octal number. In this case it's still 2, but 020 would be 16. Don't use leading zeros, unless you actually want octal numbers.

Comment: you're right, I wrote this on the fly!